# Username and role

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have this databases: `table<User>(UserID,Name,Surname,Username,Password,Email)`, `table<Role>(RoleID,RoleName,Description)`, and `table<UsersInRole>(UserID,RoleID)`. I create a login authentication with username and password to access to the application (with Linq ToSql to store data), and it is right.
Now I wish to create a role for each user, but I don't know how work out it; I saw some features about it but it refers to web.app.

This is the code of the procedure that applies to login:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public bool ValidateApplicationUser(string userName, string password)
        {
          {
                var AuthContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                var query = from c in  AuthContext.Users
                            where (c.Username == userName.ToLower() && c.Password == password.ToLower())
                            select c;

                if(query.Count() != 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        }

        private void mahhh(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool authenticated = true;
            {
                if (usernameTextBox.Text !="" && passwordTextBox.Text != "")
                {
                    authenticated = ValidateApplicationUser(usernameTextBox.Text , passwordTextBox.Text);
                }

            }
            if (!authenticated)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid login. Try again.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congradulations! You're a valid user!");
                Window3 c = new Window3();
                c.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to implement a method to assign a role to the user.
Do you have any idea or suggest to make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try not to store passwords in the database; it is better to store a hash. I'm not quite sure what you mean "assign a role to the user" - are you having difficulty getting the role from the db? Or are you unsure what to do with it afterwards? If the latter, the "principal" is the way to go; at the simplest level:

```
        string username = ...
        string[] roles = ...
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity(username), roles);
```

Now you can use role-based security, either declarative or imperative.

Declarative:

```
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="ADMIN")]
    public void Foo()
    { // validated automatically by the .NET runtime ;-p

    }
```

Imperative:

```
    static bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        return principal != null && principal.IsInRole(role);
    }
    ...
    bool isAdmin = IsInRole("ADMIN");
```

Comment: As a supplement to @Marc Gravell's post:<br/>
A good article at MSDN ["How to: Create GenericPrincipal and GenericIdentity Objects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9dd5fx0.aspx)

Comment: Hi Marc,
my purpose is for example i have a username "employee1" so i will give it the role to access to the application to view only some window and deny to delete,add and edit the database.So after authenticate in the application i wish assign the role for the user"employee1".Thanks for your reply

Comment: Hi MArc sincerely i don't know how go ahead so i ask you if you can post an example (code) to understand better the procedure to work out my trouble.By the way i'm looking also to store a hash ....
Have a nice day.
Bye

Comment: (have replied to direct e-mail)

Comment: Hi Marc can you explain me where i must put your code following the code of my project?
Thanks for your support.
Bye

Comment: Usually sandwiched between a login screen and the main screen.